# RE: docusign-error-this-account-lacks-sufficient-permissions-in-session-permission

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting the following error while simulating the embedded signing feature with my dev account: "This Account lacks sufficient permissions. In-Session permission required when specifying a captive recipient." I noticed from a previous post that the perm has to be added by DocuSign. Can you please advise?.

Comment: What is your demo account id?  I need that to enable the setting in your account.  Also, how long ago did you create your account, and was it through the [Dev Center](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center)?

Answer (score 2):

create a new account with new credentials but be care full while selecting why u creating this account select proper use and then go ahead. this will solve your problem..

or

change permissions in your account and choose your role in profile as admin and change settings for administrator. fill all the information very cure...

Answer (score 2):

run this command on console before moving.

```
bundle exec rake docusign_rest:generate_config
```

if u r getting success then check your config/initializers/docusign_rest.rb. there will be this code available.